# Determinant of a Lattice Code

Tags: coding-theory, integer-lattices

For a binary $[n,k,d]$ code $C$ with lattice $\Lambda (C)$ I want to show that $det(\Lambda (C)) = 2^{n-2k}$. I'm having a little trouble with demonstrating this and it would help me very much understanding lattices associated with codes.

Comment: $\Lambda(C)$ consists of those integer vectors $x\in\mathbf{Z}^n$ such that after reduction modulo two we have $x\in C$. So $2\mathbf{Z}^n\subseteq \Lambda(C)$, and $$[\Lambda(C):2\mathbf{Z}^n]=|C|=2^k.$$ I'm not sure whether you are asking about the determinant of the Gram matrix or a generator matrix of $\Lambda(C)$. Probably the latter, because that computes the measure of a fundamental region...

Comment: I'm asking about the determinant of $\Lambda (C)$ associated to code $C$ by the Sloane construction

Comment: But $\Lambda(C)$ is a lattice? Lattices don't have determinants, square matrices do :-) Consider the $[2,1,2]$ code generated by $11$. A generator matrix of the lattice $\Lambda(C)$ is
$$M=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&2\cr}.$$ Then $\det M=2$. But that is not $=2^{n-2k}=2^{2-2}=2^0=1$. So you want something else. What? Is your scaling/normalization different? Give an example of a code $C$ and the matrix whose determinant you want to calculate.